# how to accept alternate names for the attributes accepted during the deserialization in NodeJs or Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Is there any way to capture an attribute's alternate names in NodeJs?
e.g An API accepts an object as an input called requestBody, which could send a field called `mobileNumber or mobile_number or mobNumber or contact_number or contactNumber` etc,
And I wish to store them in a variable called `contact`

In Java there's annotation support via a library like fasterxml.jackson to do so
e.g

```
class Technology {
   @JsonProperty("contact")
   @JsonAlias({"mobileNumber", "mobile_number", "mobNumber", "contact_number"})
   private String contact;      
}
```

Can I do something similar in Node while parsing into a variable?

**Tried the following -**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If only one of those properties will be filled out I would use the property names as strings in an array and use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get a value for the first match. If there is no value it will return `undefined` which is `falsey` and if there is a value it will be `truthy` and return the value from that property.

```
const props = ["mobileNumber", "mobile_number", "mobNumber", "contact_number"];
const mobile = props.find((prop) => requestBody[prop]);
```